# How to get min date with date part in SQL

Tags: sql, select, mindate

I would like to ask how to get MIN DatePart from a `DateTime` column in a SQL Server `Select` query.

This is my query:

```
SELECT  
   MIN(CAST(DATEPART(DD, DateCreated) AS NVARCHAR) + 
   N'/' +
   CAST(DATEPART(MM, DateCreated) AS NVARCHAR) + 
   N'/' +
   CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, DateCreated) AS NVARCHAR)) AS DateFrom
FROM    
   [User]
```

The result should be `04/04.2013` but right now, the result is `01/04/2014`

Please help ....

Comment: What data do you have? if the min is first of April then you will get 01 and not 04. Why do you think it should be 04? As far as the fullstop instead of slash, then change it in your query as i did in my answer. If you provide sample data we will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  MIN(CAST(DATEPART(DD,DateCreated) AS NVARCHAR) + 
        N'/' +
        CAST(DATEPART(MM,DateCreated) AS NVARCHAR) + 
        N'.' +
        CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DateCreated) AS NVARCHAR)) AS DateFrom
FROM    [User]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the aggregation query like below one

```
select min(date) from tablename
```